# Thessaloniki Airport to KTEL Halkidikis bus station

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, thessaloniki, skg

I will be arriving at Thessaloniki Airport on Sunday, August 16th, and I would like to know how I can get to KTEL Halkidikis bus station using public transportation?

Answer (score 2):

By 2023 the bus line is renamed to X1 Bus during day and N1 bus during night.
https://oasth.gr/#en/routeinfo/list/61/12/73/ is the correct link right now.

Answer (score 1):

I found the 79A Bus, if someone other needs any information about the same situation, you can look to the 79A Bus, for more information look here: http://oasth.gr/#en/routeinfo/list/575/78/69/